# Глобальный хук на PrintScreen

Tags: c#

Вот так я делаю хук:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace ScreenShooter
{
    class Hooker
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        public delegate void dUserFunc();
        private int WH_KEYBOARD_LL; // Номер глобального LowLevel-хука на клавиатуру
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100; // Сообщения нажатия клавиши
        private bool pressed = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// Функция выполняемая при срабатывании хука
        /// </summary>
        public event dUserFunc onPressHook;

        private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool Pressed
        {
            get { return pressed; }
        }

        public int Key
        {
            get { return WH_KEYBOARD_LL; }
            set { WH_KEYBOARD_LL = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Устанавливаем глобальный хук
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Key">Код клавиши</param>
        public void SetHook()
        {
            if (WH_KEYBOARD_LL != 0)
            {
                IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
                hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInstance, 0);
            } else
            {
                throw new Exception("Не назначена клавиша для глобального хука");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Снимаем хук клавиатуры
        /// </summary>
        public void UnHook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }

        private IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                //////ОБРАБОТКА НАЖАТИЯ

                if (onPressHook != null)
                    {
                    onPressHook();
                    pressed = true;
                    }
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
            else
            {
                pressed = false;
                return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, (int)wParam, lParam);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

однако это не срабатывает на <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> (код клавиши).
Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Добавьте код, так как ссылка может быть недействительна!

Comment: Возможно, решение есть в [исходном коде ShareX](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX), тоже делает скриншоты, тоже на шарпе.

Comment: спасибо! Посмотрю сорсы

Comment: Что-то никак не получается мне разобрать что и как там в ShareX, опыта наверное маловато :(

Answer (score 0):

В **[этой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/316012/)** статье есть пример перехвата PrintScreen и комбинации Alt+PrintScreen